# How to use the member type iterator of std::list with a while loop to make simple changes to a list

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, nested-loops, stdlist

I create and modify a simple list. I replace the element at index 1 of the list. How would I semantically accomplish the same thing with a while loop. The tutorial instructor remarked that the current code is quite ugly and a while loop would accomplish the same thing in a much more simple and pretty fashion. I can't figure it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<int> numbers;

    numbers.push_back(1);
    numbers.push_back(2);
    numbers.push_back(3);
    numbers.push_front(0);

    std::list<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin();
    it++;
    numbers.insert(it, 100);
    std::cout << "Current element is: " << *it << '\n';

    std::list<int>::iterator eraseIt = numbers.begin();
    eraseIt++;
    eraseIt = numbers.erase(eraseIt);
    std::cout << "erasing at element: " << *eraseIt << '\n';

    for (std::list<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end();) {
        if (*it == 2) {
            numbers.insert(it, 1234);
        }
        if (*it == 1) {
            it = numbers.erase(it);
        } else {
            it++;
        }

    }

    for (std::list<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end();
            it++) {
        std::cout << *it << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor note: You should almost never be using postfix increment on C++ iterators, and it's completely pointless when it's a standalone statement (the result of the expression is not used), because it forces the original iterator to be copied, only to throw away the copy, when prefix increment would operate in place with no copies involved. In C++, get in the habit of using prefix increment by default, and only use postfix increment if you *need* the unique behavior it provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do this if iterators are required:

```
// ...

std::list<int>::iterator it = ++numbers.begin();
numbers.insert(it, 100);
std::cout << "Current element is: " << *it << '\n';

std::list<int>::iterator eraseIt = ++numbers.begin();
eraseIt = numbers.erase(eraseIt);
std::cout << "erasing at element: " << *eraseIt << '\n';

it = numbers.begin();
while (it != numbers.end())
{
    if (*it == 2) {
        numbers.insert(it, 1234);
    }
    if (*it == 1) {
        it = numbers.erase(it);
    }
    else {
        ++it;
    }
}

for (auto& i : numbers)
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

// ...
```

Comment: I cannot believe that `++numbers.begin()` is accepted by any compiler.

Comment: @j6t FIrstly I too thought the same. It is accepted by MSVC.